# Importing Custom fonts

Tags: fonts, war

I have to use a custom font that I have to provide myself from a .war archive compiled with Maven. The fonts are available in the following formats: 
**eot, svg, woff, woff2 and ttf.**

Firefox and Google Chrome both manage to get the files in all formats upon HTTP request but fail to use them. The web console gives the following errors depending on font file format: "rejected by sanitizer, file length is wrong, failed to download"

I have already tried using another font to be sure it wasn't caused by the file itself.

1. Are the font files corrupted when they are archived?
2. Do they have to be located in a specific spot of the archive?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Maven filters by default ressources. My problem was that the fonts where filter aka compressed. Controling where the webressources are compiled solved the problem.

```
<webResource>
<directory>src/main/resources/fonts</directory>
    <targetPath>Interface/fonts</targetPath>
    <includes>
       <include>**/**</include>
    </includes>
</webResource>
```